# Spring Security integration with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: spring-security, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does Spring Security integrates with WSO2 Identity Server? If yes, then is there any sample or tutorial available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you had any luck?? If so, could you point me in the right direction?

I'm researching on the same topic, you should take a lookt at:

- [Spring Security Extensions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions.html)
- [Spring Security Extensions Git Web Interface](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/se-security)

You could use either SAML2 or Kerberos to authenticate against WSO2 Identity Server, although I have not tested this yet, but should work.

Answer (score -1):

If this is related Spring Security OAuth2 Integration with WSO2 IS.
Actually, there are 2 different ways to integrate Spring OAuth with WSO2 Identity Server:

- using the WSO2 IS admin web services like OAuthAdminService, OAuth2TokenValidationService
- sharing the database (not recommended, your application shouldn't have access to the identity provider database)

It's quite easy to integrate Spring OAuth with WSO2 Identity Server, of course, you could reimplement all TokenStore methods or the DefaultTokenServices to provide even more functionality and make the integration as transparent as you like but this sample is meant to show the very first steps.

You can refer the below blog https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-spring-oauth2-integration-with-identity-server